# Issue in replacing text using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a text "new discussion" in span.
I have written the code to replace it with "New Discussion"

```
var newDiscussionVar = $("span:contains('new discussion')");
$(newDiscussionVar).hide();
$(newDiscussionVar).text("New Discussion");
```

However, it is hiding the whole body content

Comment: can you share your html sample?

Comment: Well, `hide()` does hide the entire element ?

Comment: It should only hide that span, not the entire body.

Comment: what is your html structure?

Comment: I'm guessing the *"body content"* means the entire text in the span, and not just the text in the selector, and that's the expected behaviour. There's no way this would hide the entire `body`

Comment: tag soup might cause this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_soup

Comment: in html source, I am not able to find this span, since this is a webpart added on sharepoint site, however, I am able to find the content using jquery (contains)

Comment: look in live html in browser console

Comment: .....<span>new discussion</span>.... just this snippet related to that

Comment: @Aquarius24 Check my updated answer. Might It help you

Answer (score -1):

```
$("span").text(function () {
   return $("span").text().replace("new discussion", "New Discussion"); 
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kCnD8/30/)**

Comment: would affect every span on the page!! Don't see how this would help anything. Also no way to be sure from what is known that the first child node is the target